# Replacing values based on conditions

Tags: r, regex, replace

I have a dataframe one of the cols is `id` and some of the values have been messed up during the recording of the data.

here's an example of the type of data

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Id = c("'110171786'", "'1103fbfd5'", "'0700edf6dc'", 
"'1103fad09'", "'01103fc9bb'", "''", "''", "0000fba2b'", "'01103fb169'", 
"'01103fd723'", "'01103f9c34'", "''", "''", "''", "'01103fc088'", 
"'01103fa6d8'", "'01103fb374'", "'01103fce8c'", "'01103f955d'", 
"'011016e633'", "'01103fa0da'", "''", "''", "''", "'01103fa4bd'", 
"'01103fb5c4'", "'01103fd0d7'", "'01103f9e2e'", "'01103fc657'", 
"'01103fd4d1'", "'011016e78e'", "'01103fbda2'", "'01103fbae7'", 
"'011016ee23'", "'01103fc847'", "'01103fbfbb'", "''", "'01103fb8bb'", 
"'01103fc853'", "''", "'01103fbcd5'", "'011016e690'", "'01103fb253'", 
"'01103fcb19'", "'01103fb446'", "'01103fa4fa'", "'011016cfbd'", 
"'01103fd250'", "'01103fac7d'", "'011016a86e'"), Weight = c(11.5, 
11.3, 11.3, 10.6, 10.6, 8.9, 18.7, 10.9, 11.3, 18.9, 18.9, 8.6, 
8.8, 8.4, 11, 10.4, 10.4, 10.8, 11.2, 11, 10.3, 9.5, 8.1, 9.3, 
10.2, 10.5, 11.2, 21.9, 18, 17.8, 11.3, 11.5, 10.8, 10.5, 12.8, 
10.9, 8.9, 10.3, 10.8, 8.9, 10.9, 9.9, 19, 11.6, 11.3, 11.7, 
10.9, 12.1, 11.3, 10.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-50L))
>
```

What I would like to do is search through the `id` column and replace the following mistakes

- some of the values have a zero missing off the front, all of these would start with a 1 now instead which makes finding them easily. So basically anything that has a character length of 9 and starts with a 1 needs a 0 as the first character.
- some of the values are less than 10 characters long, these need to be removed.
- some have more than one leading 0 and these need to be removed.

Comment: Why are your Id's double quoted eg `"'110171786'"` instead of `"110171786"`? Just curious

Comment: I think that just initially to stop excel from treating them like numbers and removing the zeros (which didn't work) and some of the IDs have an "E" in the middle and excel turns that into scientific notation. Relic of an old database system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
df$Id <- gsub("^('?)(1.{8}')$", "\\10\\2", df$Id)
df[ !grepl("^'?(00|'$)", df$Id),]
#              Id Weight
# 1  '0110171786'   11.5
# 2  '01103fbfd5'   11.3
# 3  '0700edf6dc'   11.3
# 4  '01103fad09'   10.6
# 5  '01103fc9bb'   10.6
# 9  '01103fb169'   11.3
# 10 '01103fd723'   18.9
# 11 '01103f9c34'   18.9
# 15 '01103fc088'   11.0
# 16 '01103fa6d8'   10.4
# 17 '01103fb374'   10.4
# 18 '01103fce8c'   10.8
# 19 '01103f955d'   11.2
# 20 '011016e633'   11.0
# 21 '01103fa0da'   10.3
# 25 '01103fa4bd'   10.2
# 26 '01103fb5c4'   10.5
# 27 '01103fd0d7'   11.2
# 28 '01103f9e2e'   21.9
# 29 '01103fc657'   18.0
# 30 '01103fd4d1'   17.8
# 31 '011016e78e'   11.3
# 32 '01103fbda2'   11.5
# 33 '01103fbae7'   10.8
# 34 '011016ee23'   10.5
# 35 '01103fc847'   12.8
# 36 '01103fbfbb'   10.9
# 38 '01103fb8bb'   10.3
# 39 '01103fc853'   10.8
# 41 '01103fbcd5'   10.9
# 42 '011016e690'    9.9
# 43 '01103fb253'   19.0
# 44 '01103fcb19'   11.6
# 45 '01103fb446'   11.3
# 46 '01103fa4fa'   11.7
# 47 '011016cfbd'   10.9
# 48 '01103fd250'   12.1
# 49 '01103fac7d'   11.3
# 50 '011016a86e'   10.6
```